# is there a way to hide lightning-slider range (0-100) in lwc?

Tags: lightning-web-components

[image]

is there a way to hide the range 0-100 in the standard lightning-slider component?

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll have to build your own. The actual [slider](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/slider/) is pretty basic code, though, it shouldn't take long to implement.